# I cannot execute this procedure I'm creating in oracle with sql developer, maybe a syntax error? Or can updates be used inside procedures?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

What I have to do is...
"Write a procedure to modify the location of a department. The procedure is going to get as IN params the

- Number of department to change to location (department_id)
- New location for that department (change the location_id, but giving the city name as param)
  "

IMPORTANT NOTE (IM WORKING IN THE HR DEFAULT SCHEMA OF ORACLE)

I have this Pl/SQL code

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    BEGIN
        MOD_LOCALI(&n_dep, &nueva_local);
    END;
```

And I'm trying to create this stored procedure

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE MOD_LOCALI 
(
  N_DEP IN NUMBER 
, NUEVA_LOCAL IN VARCHAR2 
) AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE departments d
    SET d.location_id = (SELECT d.location_id
                            FROM departments d
                            INNER JOIN locations l
                            ON d.location_id = l.location_id
                            WHERE l.city = NUEVA_LOCAL;
                        )
    WHERE d.department_id = N_DEP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'El departmento con número ' || N_DEP || ', se ha mudado a ' || NUEVA_LOCAL);

END MOD_LOCALI;
```

But when I execute the procedure to save it (I press the compile button in oracle sql developer), I get these errors

[image]

That's all, thanks in advance

Comment: My guess is the ";" after NUEVA_LOCAL.

Comment: that's not working ^^'' @RobertPaulsen

Comment: Both table alias `D`

Comment: well, you were right about the ";" after NUEVA_LOCAL, but it wasn't working because the code had more errors @RobertPaulsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final working pieces of code are:
**CODE FOR CALLING THE PROCEDURE**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    MOD_LOCALI(&n_dep, '&nueva_local');
END;
```

**CODE OF THE PROCEDURE**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MOD_LOCALI 
(
    N_DEP IN NUMBER, 
    NUEVA_LOCAL IN VARCHAR2
) AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE departments d
    SET d.location_id = (SELECT l.location_id
                            FROM locations l
                            WHERE l.city = NUEVA_LOCAL
                        )
    WHERE d.department_id = N_DEP;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'El departmento con número ' || N_DEP || ', se ha mudado a ' || NUEVA_LOCAL);

END MOD_LOCALI;
```

The errors I was having were

- Semicolon after NUEVA_LOCAL
- When calling the procedure, I needed to add single quotes to '&nueva_local'
- The subquery was wrong, I was doing needlessly a join where It had literally no sense at all

**PEOPLE WHO HELPED ME REACH THE CORRECT SOLUTION**

- RobertPaulsen
- Littlefoot
- Anurag

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
SQL> create or replace procedure mod_locali
  2    (n_dep       in number ,
  3     nueva_local in varchar2
  4    )
  5  as
  6  begin
  7    update departments d
  8      set d.location_id = (select d.location_id
  9                             from departments d inner join locations l
 10                                  on d.location_id = l.location_id
 11                            where l.city = nueva_local
 12                          )
 13      where d.department_id = n_dep;
 14
 15      dbms_output.put_line( 'El departmento con número ' || n_dep || ', se ha mudado a ' || nueva_local);
 16  end mod_locali;
 17  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set ver off
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2    mod_locali(&n_dep, '&nueva_local');
  3  end;
  4  /
Enter value for n_dep: 10
Enter value for nueva_local: Croatia
El departmento con número 10, se ha mudado a Croatia

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Well you were right about the error. With that the procedure could compile, but the whole meaning of the code and the procedure was wrong because in the procedure, in the subquery, I should've looked only for the location ID of a given city, I didn't need to do a join after all. I'll answer my own question with the code to call the procedure and the code for the procedure itself to show the final solution, but I'll give you credits for the help ^^

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you thought about it and found the correct approach. Thank you for letting us know.

Answer (score 1):

remove semicolon from sub query and add "/" after "end mod_locali;"

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b6b8371c5ed33b733681c5a436f44982